# Are Sunni Muslims allowed to practice Nikah mut'ah?

Tags: sunni, nikah-al-mutah, nikah

In an earlier question I asked whether a married man who sleeps with an unmarried woman is considered Zina and in some jurisdictions was punishable by stoning (Saudi Arabia, Sudan, Iran, Yemen and some states in Nigeria). The answers seemed to indicate that a married man is liable for the death penalty (whether by stoning or some other method).

But, to get around this, a private marriage contract can be performed (Nikah mut'ah)  - from my research it seems that this is a carryover from pre-Islamic practices of Arabs, and Shiite Islam does not condone it. Since most of the jurisdictions where stoning occurs are Sunni, though, I want to know what is the legal status of Nikah mut'ah in Sunni countries.

Comment: In sunni view nikah mut'ah is considered as haram, haram, haram, how could it be halal.

Answer (score 1):

Nikah mut'ah is haram in Sunni Islam.  [AskMufti.co.za](http://askmufti.co.za/mutah/) summarises it:

> Mut'ah means to 'marry a lady' for a prescribed period of time, and this is forbidden and Haraam according to all the four Madhabs.

Other Sunni fatawa declaring it haram are at: [AskImam.org](http://askimam.org/public/question_detail/17596), [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=84187), [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/20738), [SeekersHub](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2011/01/25/the-ruling-of-temporary-marriages-muta-and-the-importance-of-avoiding-arguments/).

Answer (score 0):

Mut'ah is a temporary nikah and therefore haram because when you do nikah you are promising to live with that person and commit to the responsibilities such as taking care of eachother and helping eachother become better muslims. By having a Mut'ah you are already breaking the rules by saying you will leave ther person asfter a certain amount of time. This would mean you are only marrying them for a particular purpose. It is still considered as Zina!

In no way are you performing the Sunnah by performing this haram act.

Also when Allah said you can divorce he has sent rules. The work act that Allah hates even though he has kept it as halal is divorce.

Answer (score -1):

If it was Halaal during the time of the Holy Prophet,  then it is Halaal until Qiyamah. God has created humans and God knows our chemistry best and He only makes things easy for us.
Since mutah is not easy like picking up a partner from street or clubs, but certain grooming and relationships is first developed, with conditions like Nikah, Dowry or Meher and responsibility then its not anywhere close to fornication. Its consensual and healthy for both Genders.

If Mutah is avoided,  then ppl will do same act but haram. So do what is permissible.