# When was Mut'ah prohibited?

Tags: nikah-al-mutah

Assalamualaikum, can anyone help shed some light on the conflicting ahadith on when Mut'ah was banned?

Is it during the battle of Khaybar? :

Narrated `Ali bin Abi Talib:

On the day of Khaibar, Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) forbade the Mut'a (i.e. temporary marriage) and the eating of donkey-meat.

حَدَّثَنِي يَحْيَى بْنُ قَزَعَةَ، حَدَّثَنَا مَالِكٌ، عَنِ ابْنِ شِهَابٍ، عَنْ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ، وَالْحَسَنِ، ابْنَىْ مُحَمَّدِ بْنِ عَلِيٍّ عَنْ أَبِيهِمَا، عَنْ عَلِيِّ بْنِ أَبِي طَالِبٍ ـ رضى الله عنه ـ أَنَّ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم نَهَى عَنْ مُتْعَةِ النِّسَاءِ يَوْمَ خَيْبَرَ، وَعَنْ أَكْلِ الْحُمُرِ الإِنْسِيَّةِ‏.‏

Reference    : Sahih al-Bukhari 4216
In-book reference    : Book 64, Hadith 256
USC-MSA web (English) reference  : Vol. 5, Book 59, Hadith 527

Is it during the Battle of Awtas? :

Iyas b. Salama reported on the authority of his father that Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) gave sanction for contracting temporary marriage for three nights in the year of Autas 1847 and then forbade it.

حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو بَكْرِ بْنُ أَبِي شَيْبَةَ، حَدَّثَنَا يُونُسُ بْنُ مُحَمَّدٍ، حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ الْوَاحِدِ بْنُ زِيَادٍ، حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو عُمَيْسٍ، عَنْ إِيَاسِ بْنِ سَلَمَةَ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ، قَالَ رَخَّصَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم عَامَ أَوْطَاسٍ فِي الْمُتْعَةِ ثَلاَثًا ثُمَّ نَهَى عَنْهَا ‏.‏

Reference    : Sahih Muslim 1405 f
In-book reference    : Book 16, Hadith 21
USC-MSA web (English) reference  : Book 8, Hadith 3251

Is it during the conquest of Mecca? :

Rabi' b. Sabra reported that his father went on an expedition with Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) during the Victory of Mecca, and we stayed there for fifteen days (i. e. for thirteen full days and a day and a night), and Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) permitted us to contract temporary marriage with women. So I and another person of my tribe went out, and I was more handsome than he, whereas he was almost ugly. Each one of us had a cloaks, My cloak was worn out, whereas the cloak of my cousin was quite new. As we reached the lower or the upper side of Mecca, we came across a young woman like a young smart long-necked she-camel. We said:

Is it possible that one of us may contract temporary marriage with you? She said: What will you give me as a dower? Each one of us spread his cloak. She began to cast a glance on both the persons. My companion also looked at her when she was casting a glance at her side and he said: This cloak of his is worn out, whereas my cloak is quite new. She, however, said twice or thrice: There is no harm in (accepting) this cloak (the old one). So I contracted temporary marriage with her, and I did not come out (of this) until Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) declared it forbidden.
حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو كَامِلٍ، فُضَيْلُ بْنُ حُسَيْنٍ الْجَحْدَرِيُّ حَدَّثَنَا بِشْرٌ، - يَعْنِي ابْنَ مُفَضَّلٍ - حَدَّثَنَا عُمَارَةُ بْنُ غَزِيَّةَ، عَنِ الرَّبِيعِ بْنِ سَبْرَةَ، أَنَّ أَبَاهُ، غَزَا مَعَ رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم فَتْحَ مَكَّةَ قَالَ فَأَقَمْنَا بِهَا خَمْسَ عَشْرَةَ - ثَلاَثِينَ بَيْنَ لَيْلَةٍ وَيَوْمٍ - فَأَذِنَ لَنَا رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم فِي مُتْعَةِ النِّسَاءِ فَخَرَجْتُ أَنَا وَرَجُلٌ مِنْ قَوْمِي وَلِي عَلَيْهِ فَضْلٌ فِي الْجَمَالِ وَهُوَ قَرِيبٌ مِنَ الدَّمَامَةِ مَعَ كُلِّ وَاحِدٍ مِنَّا بُرْدٌ فَبُرْدِي خَلَقٌ وَأَمَّا بُرْدُ ابْنِ عَمِّي فَبُرْدٌ جَدِيدٌ غَضٌّ حَتَّى إِذَا كُنَّا بِأَسْفَلِ مَكَّةَ أَوْ بِأَعْلاَهَا فَتَلَقَّتْنَا فَتَاةٌ مِثْلُ الْبَكْرَةِ الْعَنَطْنَطَةِ فَقُلْنَا هَلْ لَكِ أَنْ يَسْتَمْتِعَ مِنْكِ أَحَدُنَا قَالَتْ وَمَاذَا تَبْذُلاَنِ فَنَشَرَ كُلُّ وَاحِدٍ مِنَّا بُرْدَهُ فَجَعَلَتْ تَنْظُرُ إِلَى الرَّجُلَيْنِ وَيَرَاهَا صَاحِبِي تَنْظُرُ إِلَى عِطْفِهَا فَقَالَ إِنَّ بُرْدَ هَذَا خَلَقٌ وَبُرْدِي جَدِيدٌ غَضٌّ ‏.‏ فَتَقُولُ بُرْدُ هَذَا لاَ بَأْسَ بِهِ ‏.‏ ثَلاَثَ مِرَارٍ أَوْ مَرَّتَيْنِ ثُمَّ اسْتَمْتَعْتُ مِنْهَا فَلَمْ أَخْرُجْ حَتَّى حَرَّمَهَا رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏.‏

Reference    : Sahih Muslim 1406 b
In-book reference    : Book 16, Hadith 23
USC-MSA web (English) reference  : Book 8, Hadith 3253

Is it during the Farewell Pilgrimage? (Sunan ibn Majah) :

It was narrated from Rabi'bin Sabrah that his father said :
"We went out with the Messenger of Allah on the Farewell pilgrimage, and they said : 'O Messenger of Allah, (ﷺ) celibacy has become too difficult for us'. He said : 'Then make temporary marriages with these women'. So we went to them, but they insisted on setting a fixed time between us and them. They mentioned that to the Prophet and he said : 'Set a fixed time between you and them.' So I went out with a cousin of mine. He had a cloak and I had a cloak, but his cloak was finer than mine, and I was younger than him. We came to a women and she said: 'One cloak is like another.' So I married her and stayed with her that night. Then the next day I saw the Messenger of Allah standing between the Rukn (corner) and the door (of the Ka'bah), saying : 'O people, I had permitted temporary marriage for you, but Allah has forbidden it until the Day of Resurrection. however had any temporary wives, he should let them go, and do not take back anything that you had given to them.' "
حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو بَكْرِ بْنُ أَبِي شَيْبَةَ، حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدَةُ بْنُ سُلَيْمَانَ، عَنْ عَبْدِ الْعَزِيزِ بْنِ عُمَرَ، عَنِ الرَّبِيعِ بْنِ سَبْرَةَ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ، قَالَ خَرَجْنَا مَعَ رَسُولِ اللَّهِ ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ فِي حَجَّةِ الْوَدَاعِ فَقَالُوا يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ إِنَّ الْعُزْبَةَ قَدِ اشْتَدَّتْ عَلَيْنَا ‏.‏ قَالَ ‏"‏ فَاسْتَمْتِعُوا مِنْ هَذِهِ النِّسَاءِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ فَأَتَيْنَاهُنَّ فَأَبَيْنَ أَنْ يَنْكِحْنَنَا إِلاَّ أَنْ نَجْعَلَ بَيْنَنَا وَبَيْنَهُنَّ أَجَلاً فَذَكَرُوا ذَلِكَ لِلنَّبِيِّ ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ فَقَالَ ‏"‏ اجْعَلُوا بَيْنَكُمْ وَبَيْنَهُنَّ أَجَلاً ‏"‏ ‏.‏ فَخَرَجْتُ أَنَا وَابْنُ عَمٍّ لِي مَعَهُ بُرْدٌ وَمَعِي بُرْدٌ وَبُرْدُهُ أَجْوَدُ مِنْ بُرْدِي وَأَنَا أَشَبُّ مِنْهُ فَأَتَيْنَا عَلَى امْرَأَةٍ فَقَالَتْ بُرْدٌ كَبُرْدٍ ‏.‏ فَتَزَوَّجْتُهَا فَمَكَثْتُ عِنْدَهَا تِلْكَ اللَّيْلَةَ ثُمَّ غَدَوْتُ وَرَسُولُ اللَّهِ ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ قَائِمٌ بَيْنَ الرُّكْنِ وَالْبَابِ وَهُوَ يَقُولُ ‏"‏ أَيُّهَا النَّاسُ إِنِّي قَدْ كُنْتُ أَذِنْتُ لَكُمْ فِي الاِسْتِمْتَاعِ أَلاَ وَإِنَّ اللَّهَ قَدْ حَرَّمَهَا إِلَى يَوْمِ الْقِيَامَةِ فَمَنْ كَانَ عِنْدَهُ مِنْهُنَّ شَىْءٌ فَلْيُخَلِّ سَبِيلَهَا وَلاَ تَأْخُذُوا مِمَّا آتَيْتُمُوهُنَّ شَيْئًا ‏"‏ ‏.‏

Grade   : Sahih (Darussalam)
English reference    : Vol. 3, Book 9, Hadith 1962
Arabic reference     : Book 9, Hadith 2038

What's even more baffling is that the Prophet SAW prohibited the marriage at Khaybar, sanctioned it at Awtas and then made it illegal again. I don't understand this. Some detractors have used this to prove an alleged inconsistency on the part of the Prophet SAW. I need help.

Comment: You may find [Can a guy have temporary nikah only for sex](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/55493/can-a-guy-have-temporary-nikah-only-for-sex) helpful!

Answer (score 1):

It was prohibited on all of those days, as the narrations show.

On a few occasions the Prophet (ﷺ) allowed a few exceptions temporarily but then reaffirmed shortly after that it's forbidden. At the conquest of Makkah, he declared it to be forbidden until the Day of Judgement (i.e., categorically forbidden and no exceptions ever again).

(Note: The last two narrations you quoted appear to be the same "cloak" story involving the same narrator (Rabi bin Sabra). Perhaps he was just recalling the previous event? Refer to a scholar regarding the context).

Is this "inconsistency"? No.. because it's an Islamic principle that haram things done out of necessity are forgiven. Moreover, the Islamic view of it being an undesirable practice stayed the same and the Islamic goal of getting rid of it stayed the same.