# Nikkah just for desires

Tags: halal-haram

Can I do nikkah with my maid hust to full fill sexual desires and I would take care of her it would be a secret and I dont want to do zina and I dont have any chance of marriage for 1-2 years and I would divorce her later but it would not be a contract nor a agreed time.Her age is around 35 and I am 17.

Comment: We are not a fatwa site. Nikah requires witnesses and other formalities, it is unclear what you intend to do. Doing Nikah with the intention to divorce (but without a set expiry time or clause in the contract) is valid according to the majority, although the Hanbalis consider it a type of mut'a .

Answer (score -1):

Brother You are playing with fire.
Nikkah is not  a plaything.
[https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/55493/can-a-guy-have-temporary-nikah-only-for-sex#:~:text=Yes%2C%20temporary%20nikah%20is%20permissible,that%20the%20time%20if%20wishes](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/55493/can-a-guy-have-temporary-nikah-only-for-sex#:%7E:text=Yes%2C%20temporary%20nikah%20is%20permissible,that%20the%20time%20if%20wishes).
Follow the link for similar question.